How to change the log message color in Eclipse console window (TomEE)?
I remember early tomcat server, the log message (INFO) default is black in eclipse.
But late tomcat server the default color is red.
Why the INFO message default set red?
I want the INFO message color is black.
And the Error message color is red.
The setting: Windows > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console
"Standard Out text color" is black, and "Error text color" is red, that's right.
The plugin "ANSI Escape in Console" say "Starting with the 2022-09 release Eclipse supports ANSI escapes in console." "So this plugin is redundant, uninstall it to prevent conflicts: ...".
How to set the INFO message color to black, and Error message color to red?

Are the INFO log entries being written to standard out or to standard error?

Hmm..., I don't know where the TomEE log messages are coming from, I'm not sure if it's java logs or log4j or...etc. All I know is that it shows up in the Eclipse console window and is red...

I'm pretty sure "Error text color" applies to anything written to stderr, as the Console is not doing any sort of parsing on whether output has the words INFO or ERROR, in which case if both kinds of log entires are written to stderr, it should be red.

Well..., You mean TomEE or late tomcat the log message INFO and Error are both written to stderr. (So it's red)  I can't change them?

I suspect, but I can't prove it. Probably has to do with the logging setup.
